# google gcm xmpp server with http client

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I have a Java based app server and a cordova client. I want to use GCM with the existing cordova gcm plugin code which uses HTTP to communicate with GCM, and use XMPP for GCM communication in my server to make it more efficient. can this be done? I am asking because I get ACKs on my server but no messages arrive to the client.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, it was in the client side. The answer is yes, it does work.